# Significato di "incunichito"

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto questa frase:

> Agnello fuma, tutto **incunichito**, e Vita gli si avvicina, titubante.

Qualcuno di voi saprebbe spiegare il significato di "incunichito"? Non ho trovato questo vocabolo su nessun dizionario. Immagino si tratti di un termine di origine regionale, possibilmente correlato al napoletano.

Comment: Dalle righe in cui è questa frase si può capire se l’aggettivo indica una posizione (qualcosa come “rannicchiato”) o uno stato d’animo?

Comment: @Benedetta: Purtroppo, no. Non ho copiato nessun'altra frase del testo perché non credo siano di nessun aiuto.

Comment: @N74: Ne sapresti qualcosa?